# Date time picker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datepicker

I am developing a C# application where user can select any date time format and display in date time picker.How to change the format of date time picker in code?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set your own custom format, you can set the following two properties of your Date Time Picker control to achieve this:

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy mm ddd";
dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Obviously, you can replace "yyyy mm ddd" with any valid date format string.

Answer (score 0):

You can go here [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) and here to get the format of definitions
[DateTimePicker CustomFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use capital M for month ...

`dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy MM ddd";
dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;`